# Error after updating npm, cordova

Tags: cordova, umask

I updated npm and cordova, after which I'm not able to run any of the cordova commands from terminal. Here is the error which I get:

```
Avinash-mac-mini:~ avinash$ cordova
module.js:339
    throw err;


Error: Cannot find module 'umask'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/umask.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Comment: Can you try installing again on top of it using $ npm install -g cordova@latest

Comment: I uninstalled cordova and installed it again, that didn't help either. Tried clearing npm cache, also didn't help. Then I completely removed npm and did a fresh install of everything. Working fine now.

Comment: try `npm uninstall -g cordova

npm install -g cordova@latest`

Comment: I got the same problem and @frazras comment works as answer.

Comment: Yes, @frazras comment works as answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try executing

```
npm uninstall -g cordova 
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem for cordova build ios command.
According cordova documentation(https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html) :

> After you run the npm command above to update Cordova itself, you may
>   need to ensure your project's resources conform to the latest
>   version's requirements. Run a command such as the following for each
>   platform you're building:
>
> ```
> $ cordova platform update android
> $ cordova platform update ios
> ...etc.
> ```

I have solved it by updating my ios platform after cordova updation:

```
 $ cordova platform update ios
```

Comment: This wont work since the problem lies in actually running the cordova command